# Is this question about a part of smartphone concerning it repair ontopic?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if the following question is on-topic and if not if their is another Stack-Exchange site I could ask it.

From the repair tag description it seems like it is no on-topic but I just wanted to be sure and ask if there is a way change it to be on-topic:

> Questions relating to electrical/electronic repair. Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. Please ensure your questions are somewhat generic in nature so they are likely to help future visitors and not too localized to a specific piece of equipment.

I am afraid my question is to specific as it is. But I wonder if I could change it to make it more general, for example by asking more about the function of the part.

The question would be:

I am currently trying to change the display of my LG G2.

When I tried to remove the display I noticed that one screw turned through. It turned out, that the electrical part the screw is attached to detached from the board. I assume that it was already detached before I started my repair efforts. I wonder if the phone can still work with this part being lose.

So my question is: **What type of electrical part is the loose part and how does it work?**
.

[image: loose Part]
[image: loose Part 2]
[image]

Note: I had it fixed before so it was not the first time the display was replaced (not by myself)

Comment: This really isn't an electrical part. It's a mechanical fixture which seems to rely on solder for mechanical strength. There's a rule of thumb in EE which says that for commercial products solder should be assumed to be about as strong as chewing gum. While it sounds excessive, following that rule excludes failures such as the one you're having.

Comment: As long as the solder pad did not rip off the board it should be reparable. The part was most likely not soldered on to begin with, a soldering iron and some flux could fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for asking first, but I'd have to say no, it isn't on-topic, and there's no way to make it on-topic.

The biggest problem I see is that from your photographs, it isn't an electrical part at all, but rather a mechanical part. Its only electrical connection seems to be to the ground plane of the PCB. It *may* have something to do with making a shielding connection, but even then, it would be very specific to the mechanical design of that particular phone.